# PhantomJS runs fine as me, returns blank page when running under IIS

Tags: c#, iis, permissions, windows-server-2008-r2, phantomjs

I'm running an ASP MVC3 website that spins off a new process that runs phantom js, which calls a website and writes what it sees to a file.  The IIS_IUSRS group has write access to the directory.  If I run the script manually, it works fine.  If I run it under IIS, it draws a blank page.  Is there something obvious I'm missing?  Is there a way I can become the IIS user to see what the error is?

Thank you.

Edit: I figured out how to get the status of page.open.  The status is "fail".  Works under my admin account, fails under iis account.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an IIS user, but on Linux Phantomjs won't run through the server user (Apache user) and will give permission denied error. There is a workaround for linux where we need to create another bash file and provide it root access (admin access in your case). So in your case you are looking to run phantomjs through the admin user behind the scene. Sorry but I can't help more on it. The linux workaround is http://cisight.com/run-latest-phantomjs-with-shell_exec-php-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric/.

Comment: I was thinking of trying that.  I'll try that tonight.  Thanks!